# How to count total days from two dates selected with Zebra Datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

i want to count total days from two selected dates, but the result always show NaN and not the total days counted.

i have tried like this answer [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44815929/how-do-i-display-the-number-of-days-selected-from-two-dates-selected-from-zebra?newreg=ad0a6047e55b4569af30e7c3c4444140)

and i have tried with momentJS. many people advise to use momentJS. because hard to understand to me for using momentJS finally i'm back to Zebra Datepicker.

this is the form file and script from footer file

```js
<script type="javascript/text">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        bsCustomFileInput.init()
        $('#tanggal_mulai_cuti_t').Zebra_DatePicker({
            pair: $('#tanggal_akhir_cuti_t'),
            direction: 1,
            select_other_months: 1,
            onClose: function(el) {
                tampilHari(el)
            }
        })
        $('#tanggal_mulai_cuti_u').Zebra_DatePicker({
            pair: $('#tanggal_akhir_cuti_u'),
            direction: true
        })
        $('#tanggal_akhir_cuti_t').Zebra_DatePicker({
            direction: [1, 14],
            select_other_months: 1,
            onClose: function(el) {
                tampilHari(el)
            }
        })
        $('#tanggal_akhir_cuti_u').Zebra_DatePicker({
            direction: 1,
            onClose: function(el) {
                tampilHari(el)
            }
        })

        function tampilHari() {
            // get tanggal
            var start = $('#tanggal_mulai_cuti_t').val()
            var end = $('#tanggal_akhir_cuti_t').val()
            if (!start || !end) return

            // parse data
            var startArr = start.split("/")
            var endArr = end.split("/")
            var startDate = new Date(startArr[2], startArr[0] - 1, startArr[1])
            var endDate = new Date(endArr[2], endArr[0] - 1, endArr[1])

            // calculate days
            var days = Math.round((endDate - startDate) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))

            $('#total_cuti').val(days)
        }
    }
    
    $.fn.Zebra_DatePicker.defaults = {
        format: 'd/F/Y',
        show_icon: true,
        lang_clear_date: 'Hapus'
    }
</script>
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Zebra_datepicker/1.9.12/css/default/zebra_datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Zebra_datepicker/1.9.12/zebra_datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!doctype html>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 mx-auto">

            <!-- div.card -->
            <div class="card text-white bg-dark">
                <div class="card-header bg-dark">
                    <?= $title; ?>
                </div>

                <!-- div.card-body -->
                <div class="card-body">
                    <form action="<?= base_url('user/insertcutitahunan'); ?>" method="post">
                        <div class="form-row">

                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <label for="tanggal_mulai_cuti_t">Tanggal Mulai Cuti</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tanggal_mulai_cuti_t" name="tanggal_mulai_cuti_t" value="" data-zdp_readonly_element="false">
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <label for="tanggal_akhir_cuti_t">Tanggal Akhir Cuti</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tanggal_akhir_cuti_t" name="tanggal_akhir_cuti_t" value="" data-zdp_readonly_element="false">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="sisa_cuti">Sisa Cuti</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sisa_cuti" name="sisa_cuti" value="<?= $user['sisa_cuti_tahunan']; ?>" readonly>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="total_cuti">Total Cuti</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="total_cuti" name="total_cuti" readonly>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-icon-split">
                                <span class="icon text-white-50">
                                    <i class="fas fa-fw fa-save"></i>
                                </span>
                                <span class="text">Ajukan Cuti</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </form>

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</html>
```

I expect the result,
total vacation left: 30 days
date1: 10 Juli 2019
date2: 22 Juli 2019
will be (22 - 10). You have use 12 days for vacation.
Left (30 - 12) 18 days to use.